# CSS3: Vertically centered page with margin 10 pixels

Tags: css

is there a way to center the whole page with margin 10 pixels?

If you replace the **margin: 10 auto** with **margin: 0 auto** it is centered.

**HTML**

```
<body><div id="test">Test</div></body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{width:460px;margin: 10 auto}
#test{width:440px;background:#3f3f3f;color:white}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pb04rLcr/

Comment: You're missing the px from `10px`

Comment: Right.  CSS treats a zero as a zero since units could not possibly matter if you have none of them.  But if you put in a number without units, CSS won't know which units you mean and will ignore that bit of info.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you use `px`, so it should look something like this:
`margin: 10px auto;`

Hope this solves your issue

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pb04rLcr/4/)